# Rails params nulled when responding to csv format in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, parameters

I'm having a weird problem I cannot seem to figure out related to rails params.

I have a Controller where I permit any param. In this controller, a param (`csv_type`) controls which CSV file I will respond. CSV of type `registration` or `attendance`, for example.

This param is built in URL via path (e.g.: abcs_path(@abc, format: 'csv', csv_type: 'attendance') resulting in `/abcs/id.csv?csv_type=attendance`.

I would expect `{"csv_type"=>"attendance", "controller"=>"abcs", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"45", "format"=>"csv"}` but in production I get `{"controller"=>"abcs", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"45", "format"=>"csv"}`. `csv_type` is gone.

This works flawlessly locally and I get all params. Also works well on Heroku review apps. Also works well when I run locally on `RAILS_ENV=production`.

But in real production, it doesn't. It also doesn't work on staging which is configured with `RAILS_ENV=production`. Though review apps are also `RAILS_ENV=production`, which makes the whole thing a mystery.

Ideas: 
 - `nginx` messing up with domain (staging and production are on official domain, review app is Heroku domain, local is localhost).
 - sqreen somehow intercepting this
 - mime.types and https (have tried adding csv to rails, with no success). Didn't add on nginx
 - some rails config on params permit (though I'm doing `params.permit!`) on `before_action` just to make sure
 - some ENV variable messing up?
 - can't think of anything else ???

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: At Sqreen we don't touch params as they may be frozen in recent versions. In fact we even dup the params hash to prevent any conflict (we had a bug when someone else was modifying params while we were iterating on it).

Comment: `type`  and `*_type` names though, are problematic in general with Rails and best avoided, since it's naming magic for STI and polymorphic associations in ActiveRecord. Difference between development and production also includes lazy/eager loading of classes and lazy/eager definition of accessors on ActiveRecord classes, and forking web servers like puma or unicorn offer preload facilities. In any case, load order via constant referencing may or may not have an effect.

Comment: The most likely removal from params though is a mismatch in strong parameters, e.g a missing, mistyped, or misscoped `require` or `permit`.

Comment: As for generating CSV, nothing is required really. Jus make sure to send `text/csv` back as a `Content-Type` header. Protip, if CSV are to be opened in Excel, add a BOM, you'll save yourself a lot of trouble: `"\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding('UTF-8')`. As for responding to `Accept: text/csv` you may find this snippet useful: https://gist.github.com/lloeki/3c93105028b9f2ab072954f482ed8fb1 and implement a `to_csv` on whatever object you have.

Comment: I tried doing a `params.permit!` in a method and calling it from the controller that generates the CSV but still doesn't work on production because the params are just not there.

Comment: Generating the CSV is not the problem. The problem is that it's ignoring params so it only generates a csv of type "registrations" (the default one). It doesn't generate of type "admissions", for example. So, to emphasize, **the whole problem is rails ignoring param `csv_type` (but only in production)**.